# Freeform 4.1.2 EE 2.7 - forms not submitting

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Freeform 4.1.2 EE 2.7 - 
I have my forms setup and when I submit the forms not submitting, not being redirected to the redirect template no notifications.  Basically nothing is working.  After I press submit it just redirects to the home page www.domain?ACT=70

```
{exp:freeform:form
    form_name="contact"
    return="Contact/thank_you"
form_id="1"
notify_admin="yes"
admin_notify="user@domain.com"
admin_notification_template="contact" 
required="email" 
require_captcha="yes" 
}
    <dl>
    {freeform:all_form_fields}
        <dt><label>{freeform:field_label}</label></dt>
        <dd>{freeform:field_output}</dd>
    {/freeform:all_form_fields}
    </dl>
    {if freeform:captcha}
        <p>Please enter the word you see in the image below:</p>
        <p>{freeform:captcha}<br />
        <input type="text" name="captcha" style="width:140px;" /></p>
    {/if}
    <p>{freeform:submit}</p>
    {if freeform:no_results}
        <p>
            Specified form was not found. Please make sure you have
            specified the correct short name of the form in the
            <b>form_name</b> parameter.
        </p>
    {/if}
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Answer (score 3):

fond the issue, when using an index.html file as a site offline page causes the form to now work.

Removing the index.html and making the site live with the index.php file allowed the form to work

Comment: Ran into this on a site I inherited and as soon as I removed index.php the forms started working. Good find. You should accept your won answer.